# Is it possible to use another mouse for the virtual environment?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

Is it possible to attach two mouse at the same time? My main working environment is Windows 7, whereas the Virtual Environment created using VirtualBox is Ubuntu Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can attach more than one mouse.  It definitely works with two USB mice, or one notebook trackpad and USB mouse.  Both will control the same mouse pointer.  I don't know if you can dedicate one of the two a virtual machine.

Comment: Just add a USB filter to exclude one of the USB mouse.

Comment: @Sathya: What is a USB filter?

Comment: @paradroid VirtualBox allows you to set up filters so as to allow specific USB devices to be accessed by the guest

Comment: @paradroid you're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to use two mice at the same time with one operation systems (Windows).

Why don't you just try it out and see -- shouldn't hurt anything.